# Change color of CoC suggestion box

Tags: vimrc, plugin-coc

I successfully installed CoC in my Vim to have some code-suggestions/completions while coding in Rust.

It works fine, but I want to change the color and basic looks of the suggestion box.

I tried achieving this by editing the JSON file that's opened after executing `:CocConfig`. This is it's content:

```
{
    "suggest.completionItemKindLabels": {
        "keyword": "\u0000",
        "variable": "\ue79b",
        "value": "\uf89f",
        "operator": "\u03a8",
        "function": "\u0192",
        "reference": "\ufa46",
        "constant": "\uf8fe",
        "method": "\uf09a",
        "struct": "\ufb44",
        "class": "\uf0e8",
        "interface": "\uf417",
        "text": "\ue612",
        "enum": "\uf435",
        "enumMember": "\uf02b",
        "module": "\uf40d",
        "color": "\u0000",
        "property": "\ue624",
        "field": "\uf9be",
        "unit": "\uf475",
        "event": "\ufacd",
        "file": "\uf723",
        "folder": "\uf114",
        "snippet": "\ue60b",
        "typeParameter": "\uf728",
        "default": "\u0000"
    }
}
```

I tried to change the color of the suggestion-box with that code as a test, but nothing has changed (even after restarting Vim).

Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:**
vimrc file after suggestion Maxim Kim:

```
set nocompatible
" Initialisation de pathogen
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()

set number
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set smartindent
set autoindent

filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
runtime! config/**/*.vim

autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
autocmd BufWinEnter * NERDTreeMirror
"autocmd BufWinEnter * NERDTreeMinor

set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\ SemiBold:h16

let NERDTreeMinimalUI = 1
let NERDTreeDirArrows = 1
set laststatus=2

let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline_theme='minimalist'

colorscheme afterglow


set guioptions-=r  "remove right-hand scroll bar
set guioptions-=L

set scrolloff=5


"nnoremap <ScrollWheelUp> k
"nnoremap <ScrollWheelDown> j

autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) | q | endif


"OMNISHARP C# CONFIG
"" Use the vim-plug plugin manager: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug
" Remember to run :PlugInstall when loading this vimrc for the first time, so
" vim-plug downloads the plugins listed.
silent! if plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'OmniSharp/omnisharp-vim'
Plug 'w0rp/ale'
call plug#end()
endif

" Note: this is required for the plugin to work
filetype plugin indent on

" Use the stdio OmniSharp-roslyn server
let g:OmniSharp_server_stdio = 1

" Set the type lookup function to use the preview window instead of echoing it
"let g:OmniSharp_typeLookupInPreview = 1

" Timeout in seconds to wait for a response from the server
let g:OmniSharp_timeout = 5

" Don't autoselect first omnicomplete option, show options even if there is only
" one (so the preview documentation is accessible). Remove 'preview' if you
" don't want to see any documentation whatsoever.
set completeopt=longest,menuone,preview

" Fetch full documentation during omnicomplete requests.
" By default, only Type/Method signatures are fetched. Full documentation can
" still be fetched when you need it with the :OmniSharpDocumentation command.
"let g:omnicomplete_fetch_full_documentation = 1

" Set desired preview window height for viewing documentation.
" You might also want to look at the echodoc plugin.
set previewheight=5

" Tell ALE to use OmniSharp for linting C# files, and no other linters.
let g:ale_linters = { 'cs': ['OmniSharp'] }

" Update semantic highlighting after all text changes
let g:OmniSharp_highlight_types = 3
" Update semantic highlighting on BufEnter and InsertLeave
" let g:OmniSharp_highlight_types = 2

augroup omnisharp_commands
    autocmd!

    " Show type information automatically when the cursor stops moving
    autocmd CursorHold *.cs call OmniSharp#TypeLookupWithoutDocumentation()

    " The following commands are contextual, based on the cursor position.
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <buffer> gd :OmniSharpGotoDefinition<CR>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>fi :OmniSharpFindImplementations<CR>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>fs :OmniSharpFindSymbol<CR>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>fu :OmniSharpFindUsages<CR>

    " Finds members in the current buffer
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>fm :OmniSharpFindMembers<CR>

    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>fx :OmniSharpFixUsings<CR>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>tt :OmniSharpTypeLookup<CR>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>dc :OmniSharpDocumentation<CR>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <buffer> <C-\> :OmniSharpSignatureHelp<CR>
    autocmd FileType cs inoremap <buffer> <C-\> <C-o>:OmniSharpSignatureHelp<CR>

    " Navigate up and down by method/property/field
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <buffer> <C-k> :OmniSharpNavigateUp<CR>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <buffer> <C-j> :OmniSharpNavigateDown<CR>

    " Find all code errors/warnings for the current solution and populate the quickfix window
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>cc :OmniSharpGlobalCodeCheck<CR>
augroup END

" Contextual code actions (uses fzf, CtrlP or unite.vim when available)
nnoremap <Leader><Space> :OmniSharpGetCodeActions<CR>
" Run code actions with text selected in visual mode to extract method
xnoremap <Leader><Space> :call OmniSharp#GetCodeActions('visual')<CR>

" Rename with dialog
nnoremap <Leader>nm :OmniSharpRename<CR>
nnoremap <F2> :OmniSharpRename<CR>
" Rename without dialog - with cursor on the symbol to rename: `:Rename newname`
command! -nargs=1 Rename :call OmniSharp#RenameTo("<args>")

nnoremap <Leader>cf :OmniSharpCodeFormat<CR>

" Start the omnisharp server for the current solution
nnoremap <Leader>ss :OmniSharpStartServer<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>sp :OmniSharpStopServer<CR>

" Enable snippet completion
let g:OmniSharp_want_snippet=1



" For Rust
call plug#end()
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}

call plug#end()

" Rust Pmenu color
 """ Customize colors
func! s:my_colors_setup() abort
    " this is an example
    hi Pmenu guibg=#000000 gui=NONE
    hi PmenuSel guibg=#000000 gui=NONE
    hi PmenuSbar guibg=#000000
    hi PmenuThumb guibg=#000000
endfunc

augroup colorscheme_coc_setup | au!
    au ColorScheme * call s:my_colors_setup()
augroup END
```

Comment: `highlight CocFloating` and `highlight CocErrorFloat`. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64293783/441757

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't use `coc`, so I will just share my vision on how you can try to fix this.

I assume that by suggestion box you mean regular vim Pmenu.

Try to make sure if it is actually Pmenu:

1. run `:hi Pmenu` and check the colors:

[image]

2. if it really is, then changing it would be simple, add to your `vimrc`

```
""" Customize colors
func! s:my_colors_setup() abort
    " this is an example
    hi Pmenu guibg=#d7e5dc gui=NONE
    hi PmenuSel guibg=#b7c7b7 gui=NONE
    hi PmenuSbar guibg=#bcbcbc
    hi PmenuThumb guibg=#585858
endfunc

augroup colorscheme_coc_setup | au!
    au ColorScheme * call s:my_colors_setup()
augroup END
```

3. if it is not, then try to figure out what highlights coc uses either by looking into coc doc or coc source files or try to "look" into `:hi` command output:

[image]

4. if found something related to coc, try to change color of the group using `:hi coc-group guibg=red` or smth similar. (`coc-group` is an example here).
5. if you have found what coc highlight group you want to change -- make amends to 2. and you are ok

If it is not `Pmenu` (maybe it is float window of neovim or popup of vim) then you'll have to dig out how coc passes colors to them.

**UPD**

`ColorScheme` autocommand is triggered when colorscheme is changed. You change colorscheme before autocommand is defined.

1. put `colorscheme afterglow` after augroup and autocommand definition
2. NOTE that if you use terminal vim without `termguicolors` option, then gui colors wouldn't work. You have to add `ctermbg` and `ctermfg` parameters. (I don't know what palette do you use 16 or 256, for default palette colors consult https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/ -- `ctermbg=67` should be SteelBlue or smth)

```
    hi Pmenu ctermbg=black ctermfg=white
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! That Pmenu is indeed what I want to change. However, I have added that to the bottom of my vimrc, restarted Vim, but nothing is changing. Added my full vimrc in the question

Comment: @O'Niel updated

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks mate! And I'm using terminal Vim. Can't use MacVim because of this: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22191/scrolling-with-trackpad-not-working-macvim

Comment: Thanks a lot for the share! `hi Pmenu ctermbg=black ctermfg=white` resolved it for me!

Comment: Great answer. Weirdly enoug, I am using nvim on a mac with iterm2, so it's a plain text terminal, but ctermbg and ctermfg have no effect whatsoever. But setting color values to guibg and guifg actually did the trick. Sometimes plain magic seems to happen.

Comment: @LongHike that is because you use `set termguicolors`.

Comment: @MaximKim You're right :-(

Answer (score 3):

Example of black text on white background for Haskell files

```
autocmd FileType haskell hi Pmenu ctermfg=Black ctermbg=White
autocmd FileType haskell hi PmenuSel ctermfg=Black ctermbg=White
autocmd FileType haskell hi FgCocErrorFloatBgCocFloating ctermfg=Black ctermbg=White guifg=White guibg=Black
```

Comment: `FgCocErrorFloatBgCocFloating` was the painfull one for me (and the last entry in the `hi` list)